# Make 2 counters with different storage

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to make more so just need help with how to make them different counters, i tired google and some html documents but didn't find the way to do it.

```js
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sälj  " + localStorage.clickcount + "  st.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}

function clickCounter(b) {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcountr) {
      localStorage.clickcountr = Number(localStorage.clickcountr) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcountr = 2;
    }
    document.getElementById("resultr").innerHTML = "Annu  " + localStorage.clickcountr + "  st.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resultr").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Sälj!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter(b)" type="button">Annu!</button></p>
<div id="resultr"></div>
```

1. --Sälj = first counter
2. --Annu = second counter

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you named your functions in the same way. Because of this, the second function overwrites the first one, and as result, both functions are calling the same function.

Usually you do not need to write two different functions that do the same thing. In your case, your JavaScript function should look something like this:

```
function clickCounter(id, label) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!node) {
        return console.error('Element #' + id + ' not found');
    }

    if (window.localStorage === undefined) {
        node.innerHTML = 'Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...';
    } else {
        var key = 'clickcount_' + id;
        localStorage[key] = (++localStorage[key] || 1);
        node.innerHTML = label + ' ' + localStorage[key] + ' st.';
    }
}
```

And your buttons:

```
<p><button onclick="clickCounter('result', this.innerHTML)" type="button">Sälj!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter('resultr', this.innerHTML)" type="button">Annu!</button></p>
<div id="resultr"></div>
```

Comment: it works better now but how do i make 2 diffrent names for the pop up ?

Comment: @TobbeT Oh! I missed that. Check my update. Аs a name it will use the HTML of the button. If you need another name, just replace the `this.innerHTML`.

Comment: thanks but it dosent work it gets the name undifined

Comment: @TobbeT Be careful! I updated the JavaScript function as well as HTML buttons.

Comment: now it works thanks one last this is there anyway to key bind to the buttons?